# Woocommerce Product URL goes to media image of product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

My Woocommerce product pages were working fine but now all 3 of my product URLs go to the media image of that product. If I duplicate the product in WooCommerce and preview page the problem seems to resolve itself. However if I trash the old products and replace them with new ones I believe I'll lose the existing order information, so I don't want to do that. This is my first post on Stack Overflow so please forgive me if this post doesn't follow a particular convention.

Example

Going to: https://peakchalk.com/product/chunky-chalk/
instead opens: https://peakchalk.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/chunky-chalk.jpg

Any guidance on how to resolve this issue quickly is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Bcs of the slug. Thats normal and avoid having posts with same slugs. That is intended.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I reuploaded the product image and changed the slug however now I get a 404 when I go to the product listing, however Google Search Console URL inspection says the page is still indexed.

Comment: The link you posted goes to a product page. Not to a media file. Either you have resolved the issue by now, or some weird caching behaviour is going on. Try clearing the cache…

Comment: Thank you for checking Klaassiek, I have indeed resolved the issue now, I believe it was a cache issue.